# Angular Material , menu should not be visible after the mouse exit

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using angular material to display a menu and the menu will be displayed on the mouseover of the md-button. But if I didn't select an option and exit the menu, the menu is not being closed.  The JS code is like

```
angular.module('MyApp',['DirectiveApp'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
      $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };

    $scope.alertUser = function(args){
        alert("You Clicked : "+args);
    };
});
```

The html code is like

```
<md-menu>
              <md-button ng-mouseover="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">Call Button</md-button>
              <md-menu-content width="4">
                     <md-menu-item>
                          <md-button ng-click="alertUser('Redial')">
                            Redial
                          </md-button>
                        </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item>
                      <md-button ng-click="alertUser('Voicemail')">
                        Check voicemail
                      </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
          </md-menu>
```

Please find the link to plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CgRs1YbPwrJVlvJyNHyu?p=preview)

Comment: You would have to trigger modal close on ng-mouseleave event.

Comment: the problem is with md-menu. As of now it doesn't expose any API for closing the menu. if the provide it you can simply use. `ng-mouseleave="$mdCloseMenu(ev)"`

Comment: How to close the modal ?

Comment: there is no modal, its menu.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution? And is there bug report for this with the angular team?

Comment: I filed this bug report: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8006